# ffmpeg generate text file for each frame with subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg

I am burning subtitles and extracting frames, I would like to generate text files with subtitles for each extracted frames that contains subtitles, all within ffmpeg (or maybe modifying source code).

My first attempt has been a script that map the frame number to a subtitle by retrieving the time using a formula based on the extracted frame numbe and the frame rate of the extraction and looking for corresponding time in the subtitle file. Unfortunately this does not give a 100% accuracy, so now I am looking for ways to do it within ffmpeg directly.

I have taken a look at the source code, it is relatively complex and I can't find a way to catch the moments where I know that I am extracting a frame with a subtitle.

Is it possible to achieve this within ffmpeg without touching the source code?
Otherwise, could someone help me spot the relevant parts of the source code?

Thanks

Comment: Generating text files means that there will be one text file for each image, containing just the subtitle text that is shown in the image?

Comment: Yes, for each one that is extracted.